# Getting an error (DPI-1047) while connecting to Oracle RDS with AWS Lambda

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, cx-oracle

I'm using an AWS Lambda function (in Python) to connect to an Oracle database (RDS) using cx_Oracle library. But it is giving me the below error - "DPI-1047: Cannot locate a 64-bit Oracle Client library: "libclntsh.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory".

Steps I've followed -

1. Created a python virtual environment and downloaded the cx_Oracle library on an EC2 instance.
2. Uploaded the downloaded library on S3 bucket and created a Lambda Layer with it
3. Used this layer in the Lambda function to connect to the Oracle RDS
4. Used below command to connect to the DB -

conn = cx_Oracle.connect(user="*user-name*", password="*password*", dsn="*DB-Endpoint*:1521/"*database-name*",encoding="UTF-8")

Please help me in resolving this issue.

Comment: How exaclty did you create `libclntsh.so`? Did you compile it against lambda linux environment?

Comment: @Marcin - I've not compiled it separately. I've added a lambda layer that has the cx_Oracle lib.

Comment: Search stackoverflow for similar questions.

Answer (score 1):

Set the environment variable `DPI_DEBUG_LEVEL` to the value `64` and then rerun your code. The debugging output should help you figure out what is being searched. Note that you need to have the 64-bit instant client installed as well!

Comment: Thanks for your help! I’m nw getting below error -

load with name /opt/python/libclntsh.so
load by OS failure: /opt/python/libclntsh.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
load with OS search heuristics
load with name libclntsh.so
load by OS failure: libclntsh.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
load with name libclntsh.so.19.1

And there are similar errors for files till libclntsh.so.21.1

Comment: Please show the complete output in your question. The error does appear to indicate that the shared library cannot be found -- check LD_LIBRARY_PATH (which must be set *BEFORE* you launch your application) or ld configuration.

Comment: As of 2022, the easiest solution is to use the new 'Thin' mode of the latest release of the driver (which got renamed from cx_Oracle to python-oracledb) since this thin mode doesn't need Oracle Client libraries. See the [release announcement](https://cjones-oracle.medium.com/open-source-python-thin-driver-for-oracle-database-e82aac7ecf5a).

Answer (score 0):

The reason I faced this issue was that I just downloaded cx_Oracle library. In order to connect to the Oracle database from the Lambda function, we need to download the Oracle client and libaio libraries as well and club them with cx_Oracle to create a Lambda Layer. Once I followed these steps, I was able to connect to the Oracle database and query its tables. I've created a video for this process, so that others need not go through the issues I faced. Hope it will be helpful to all - https://youtu.be/BYiueNog-TI